# Excluding Special Char's in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query to clean up / drop some exceptions in the data.  My data contains elements such as the below -

```
VALUE-
<4.5
```

What I need in this case is either drop these rows because of the special char's or return the following

```
VALUE
4.5
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/replace-remove-special-characters-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple update and replace

```
UPDATE dbo.table 
Set Column1 = Replace(Column1, '<', '')
```

And any other

```
UPDATE dbo.table 
Set Column1 = Replace(Replace(Column1, '<', ''), ';', '')
```